# List of integers to single integer - Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

I seem to be struggling with something that should be extremely simple in Haskell, but I just cannot figure it out and I need some help. I am trying to convert a list of integers ([3,2,1]) and convert it to a single integer (321).

Here is what I have so far:

```
fromDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
fromDigits [] = 0;
fromDigits (x:xs) = x : fromDigits (xs)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you intend your program to do if the input list has multi-digit numbers, such as `[3, 21, 0]`?

Comment: You'll need to account for the position each number, and, (IIRC), raise the number to the base (I'm guessing 10 here), and add it to the previous numbers.

Comment: They will not be allowed, I am just doing numbers from 0-9, nothing 10+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [worker wrapper](https://wiki.haskell.org/Worker_wrapper) approach to do this:

```
fromDigits :: [Integer] -> Integer
fromDigits xs = aux xs 0
    where aux [] acc = acc
          aux (x:xs) acc  = aux xs ((acc * 10) + x)
```

Demo:

```
λ> fromDigits [3,2,1]
321
```

Or even you can use the higher order function `foldl`:

```
λ> foldl' (\acc x -> (acc * 10) + x) 0 [1,2,3]
123
```

Answer (score 3):

This is **not** a conversion. The list `[3,2,1]` may “look” like the number `321`, but it's not a one-to-one relation (as Greg alluded – `[32,1]` looks like the same number), and most certainly not a canonical one (why would you use base 10? Is this actually hexadecimal?) Hence there is really no reason why this *should* be particularly simple in Haskell<sup>1</sup>. [This is not JavaScript, fortunately](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat).

Repeat of message... it *looks* like the number `321`, and that's all, it's not related to the number in really any meaningful way. So, if you really need to implement this function of questionable worth (I think you shouldn't), then you might as well do the hack to actually exploit the “looks like” thing. I.e.,

```
fromDigits = read . filter (not . (`elem`"[,]")) . show
```

This uses the `Show` instance of lists, to *convert* the list `[3,2,1]` into an actual string `"[3,2,1]"`, then throws away the list-related characters, and reads the concatenated string `"321"` back, yielding the number `321`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Apart from the fact that it's generally quite simple to implement pure functions in Haskell...</sub>